# Agrupar registros por columna sin el valor null (Sql Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Estimados amigos tengo el sgte query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TOTALHORAS') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TOTALHORAS;
END 

SET LANGUAGE SPANISH; 
CREATE TABLE #TOTALHORAS(
EMPLSECCION VARCHAR(100),
EMPLMINUTOS VARCHAR(100),
EMPLMINUTOSN VARCHAR(100),
EMPLVALORA NUMERIC(18,2),
EMPLVALORN NUMERIC(18,2),
EMPLFEC INT);

INSERT INTO #TOTALHORAS(EMPLSECCION,EMPLMINUTOS,EMPLVALORA)
SELECT  
    S.SECCION AS SECCION,   
    CONVERT(varchar(4),isnull((SUM((DATEPART(HOUR, M.Mov_NHora) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, M.Mov_NHora)) / 60),0)) +':'+ CONVERT(varchar(4),isnull(SUM((DATEPART(HOUR, M.Mov_NHora) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, M.Mov_NHora)) % 60,0)) TOTALMIN, 
    SUM(M.Mov_VHora)AS TOTALHORASPAG
    FROM HIS_MOV_HORA M
    INNER JOIN TBL_EMPLEADO E
    ON E.EMPL_COD = M.Mov_CodEmpleado AND E.EMPL_FECH_AF > 0 AND (M.Mov_Fecha>='29/10/2018' AND M.Mov_Fecha<='04/11/2018')  
    INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S
    ON M.Mov_CodSecuencia=S.ID_CODIGO  
    GROUP BY S.ID_CODIGO, S.CUENTA_CONTABLE_AF, S.SECCION
    ORDER BY S.SECCION ASC

INSERT INTO #TOTALHORAS(EMPLSECCION,EMPLMINUTOSN,EMPLVALORN)
SELECT  
    S.SECCION AS SECCION,   
    CONVERT(varchar(4),isnull((SUM((DATEPART(HOUR, M.Mov_NHora) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, M.Mov_NHora)) / 60),0)) +':'+ CONVERT(varchar(4),isnull(SUM((DATEPART(HOUR, M.Mov_NHora) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, M.Mov_NHora)) % 60,0)) TOTALMIN, 
    SUM(M.Mov_VHora)AS TOTALHORASPAG
    FROM HIS_MOV_HORA M
    INNER JOIN TBL_EMPLEADO E
    ON E.EMPL_COD = M.Mov_CodEmpleado AND E.EMPL_FECH_AF = 0 AND (M.Mov_Fecha>='29/10/2018' AND M.Mov_Fecha<='04/11/2018')
    INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S
    ON M.Mov_CodSecuencia=S.ID_CODIGO
    GROUP BY S.ID_CODIGO, S.CUENTA_CONTABLE_AF, S.SECCION
    ORDER BY S.SECCION ASC




;WITH VISTA AS(
SELECT DISTINCT EMPLSECCION,
(SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (EMPLMINUTOS>'0') THEN EMPLMINUTOS END,'00:00')) AS EMPLMINUTOS,
(SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (EMPLVALORA>0) THEN EMPLVALORA END,0))AS EMPLVALORA,
(SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (EMPLMINUTOSN>'0') THEN EMPLMINUTOSN END,'00:00'))AS EMPOLMINUTOSN,
(SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (EMPLVALORN>0) THEN EMPLVALORN END,0)) AS EMPLVALORN
FROM #TOTALHORAS
GROUP BY EMPLSECCION,EMPLMINUTOS,EMPLVALORA,EMPLMINUTOSN,EMPLVALORN)

SELECT DISTINCT EMPLSECCION,EMPLMINUTOS,SUM (EMPLVALORA)AS EMPLVALORA,EMPOLMINUTOSN,SUM(EMPLVALORN) AS EMPLVALORN FROM VISTA GROUP BY EMPLSECCION,EMPLMINUTOS,EMPOLMINUTOSN
```

Y me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: Query Sq]

Pero yo lo deseo visualizar de la siguiente manera:

[image: Query Deseado]

Si alguien me podría ayudar indicando como podría modificar el query para que quede como en la 2da imagen.

De antemano.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está en que no has comprendido cómo funciona la agrupación en SQL. Una vez lo comprendas, escribir la consulta que genere los resultados que esperas es trivial.

Cambia el último query por:

```
select   emplseccion
       , sum(emplminutos) as emplminutos
       , sum(emplvalora) as emplvalora
       , sum(empolminutosn) as empolminutosn
       , sum(emplvalorn) as emplvalorn
  from vista 
 group by emplseccion
```

Te recomiendo entender como funciona este query y compararlo con tu query original para profundizar en la comprensión de este tema que es crucial para cualquier programador SQL.

Comment: Buenas tardes, intente como tu me dijiste pero lamentablemente me arroja el siguiente error: Mens. 8117, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 53
El tipo de datos varchar del operando no es válido para el operador sum. , ya que ese campo no es numérico sino nvarchar debido a que el resultado es la suma de horas

Comment: Ahhh, tu almacenas las horas como `varchar`?? en ese caso, sugeriría primero que nada almacenar otra cosa. Almacenar un dato como tiempos en _strings_ te va a causar algunos dolores de cabeza. Debes convertir primero de la cadena a algún tipo de dato que se pueda sumar y luego de nuevo a cadena. Para ello te puedes escribir algunas funciones que hagan la conversión y adaptar el query de mi sugerencia para utilizar estas funciones.

Answer (score 1):

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TOTALHORAS') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TOTALHORAS;
END 

SET LANGUAGE SPANISH; 
CREATE TABLE #TOTALHORAS(
EMPLSECCION VARCHAR(100),
EMPLMINUTOS VARCHAR(100),
EMPLMINUTOSN VARCHAR(100),
EMPLVALORA NUMERIC(18,2),
EMPLVALORN NUMERIC(18,2),
EMPLFEC INT);

INSERT INTO #TOTALHORAS(EMPLSECCION,EMPLMINUTOS,EMPLVALORA)
SELECT  
    S.SECCION AS SECCION,   
    M.MOV_NHORA AS HORAS,   
    (M.MOV_VHORA)AS TOTALHORASPAG
    FROM HIS_MOV_HORA M
    INNER JOIN TBL_EMPLEADO E
    ON E.EMPL_COD = M.MOV_CODEMPLEADO AND E.EMPL_FECH_AF > 0 AND (M.MOV_FECHA>='22/10/2018' AND M.MOV_FECHA<='28/10/2018')  
    INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S
    ON M.MOV_CODSECUENCIA=S.ID_CODIGO  
    --GROUP BY S.ID_CODIGO, S.CUENTA_CONTABLE_AF, S.SECCION,M.MOV_NHORA,M.MOV_VHORA
    ORDER BY S.SECCION ASC

INSERT INTO #TOTALHORAS(EMPLSECCION,EMPLMINUTOSN,EMPLVALORN)
SELECT  
    S.SECCION AS SECCION,   
    M.MOV_NHORA AS HORAS,   
    (M.MOV_VHORA)AS TOTALHORASPAG
    FROM HIS_MOV_HORA M
    INNER JOIN TBL_EMPLEADO E
    ON E.EMPL_COD = M.MOV_CODEMPLEADO AND E.EMPL_FECH_AF = 0 AND (M.MOV_FECHA>='22/10/2018' AND M.MOV_FECHA<='28/10/2018')
    INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S
    ON M.MOV_CODSECUENCIA=S.ID_CODIGO
    ORDER BY S.SECCION ASC            

;WITH VISTA AS(
SELECT EMPLSECCION,
(SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (EMPLMINUTOS>'0') THEN EMPLMINUTOS END,'00:00')) AS EMPLMINUTOS,
(SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (EMPLVALORA>0) THEN EMPLVALORA END,0))AS EMPLVALORA,
(SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (EMPLMINUTOSN>'0') THEN EMPLMINUTOSN END,'00:00'))AS EMPLMINUTOSN,
(SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (EMPLVALORN>0) THEN EMPLVALORN END,0)) AS EMPLVALORN
FROM #TOTALHORAS)

SELECT DISTINCT EMPLSECCION,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),ISNULL((SUM((DATEPART(HOUR, EMPLMINUTOS) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, EMPLMINUTOS)) / 60),0)) +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),ISNULL(SUM((DATEPART(HOUR, EMPLMINUTOS) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, EMPLMINUTOS)) % 60,0)) TOTALMIN, 
SUM (EMPLVALORA)AS EMPLVALORA,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),ISNULL((SUM((DATEPART(HOUR, EMPLMINUTOSN) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, EMPLMINUTOSN)) / 60),0)) +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),ISNULL(SUM((DATEPART(HOUR, EMPLMINUTOSN) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, EMPLMINUTOSN)) % 60,0)) TOTALMINA,    
SUM(EMPLVALORN) AS EMPLVALORN FROM VISTA GROUP BY EMPLSECCION
ORDER BY EMPLSECCION
```

Después de varios días de intento llegue a la solución de la pregunta y adjunto el código final para dar por solucionado el tema.